# How to center two buttons together on a page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to center two buttons to the center of a page. The following is my code. It centers only the btnExport at the center but not the btnReset, it always stays at the left. When I tried pull-right or pull-left at the row level both buttons correctly go to left or right!

```
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 18px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <asp:button SkinID="whiteButton" id="btnReset" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Reset" onclick="btnReset_Click"></asp:button>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <asp:button SkinID="blueButton" id="btnExport" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Export"></asp:button>
    <input class="hidden" type="button" name="btnPrint" id="btnPrint" onClick="printDiv('divInvoiceGrid');" value="Print">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `display:block` to that div style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Tried, didn't help!

Comment: your code seems to work as is https://jsfiddle.net/x9aaf1ge/ . If you are using bootstrap then I think the problem arises from there.

Comment: I always use a self-defined class for this: `.btn-row { width:100%;text-align:center }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a center class in your CSS and add it to the div that contains the two buttons.

```
.center {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Text-align center will just center the text, if I understand you want to center the buttons.

try using bootstrap `col-xx` and `col-xx-offset`.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 18px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <asp:button  SkinID="whiteButton" id="btnReset" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Reset" onclick="btnReset_Click"></asp:button>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <asp:button SkinID="blueButton"  id="btnExport" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Export"></asp:button>
        <input class="hidden" type="button" name="btnPrint" id="btnPrint" onClick="printDiv('divInvoiceGrid');" value="Print">
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did u try ?

```
.row { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
```

It would be more helpful if you could pics with what u got and what u are trying to do.